# Is there a way to auto Rerun an exe after it has finished running once

Tags: rabbitmq

I have exe which runs for 4-5 days, without a fixed frequency.
I have to manually restart it everytime it finishes running.
Is there a way to automate that?

Maybe using RabbitMQ or other Messaging brokers to queue messages to rerun it on completing execution once

Answer (score 0):

In the Windows command line execute `mycommand && mycommand`. The `&&` operator will wait until first the command is executed successfully and then execute the second one. In your case the first and second one are identical, so you achieve the double execution you want.